# WebBrowser .NET Windows Forms - Cut/Hide parts from the page

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

**Hello**,

if i come from an URL, is it possible to cut or hide parts from the orginal Webpage in the webBrowser.Net component?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented your function at WPF as below:
Write the below code at DocumentComplete Event:

```
webbrowser1.Document.getElementById("id1").SetAttribute("style","display:none;");
```

I think you can follow my way at Windows form